# Link to config file in .Net setup project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, configuration-files, setup-project

I am creating an installer for my C# application, and I want to put a link to the configuration file into the start menu, so that users can open it for editing in notepad from the program folder in the start menu.

I seem not to be able to put a link to it however - does anyone know how to do this? (Really, I would just love to put "[targetdir]\myapp.exe.config but VS doesn't let me edit the field, only select from a file browser).

Many thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the config file added in your installer? You should be able to select it when prompted for the shortcut target (the "Select Item in Project" dialog). Please note that in this prompt dialog you first need to browse to the folder which contains it (for example double-click "Application Folder").

If the config file is not added, you need to manually add it in "Application Folder". Only then you can create a shortcut to it.

Please note that Visual Studio doesn't support shortcuts to a specific file from a project output which generates multiple files. In this case you can try using a custom action which creates the shortcut through custom code.

Comment: The config file is added as part of the "Primary output from project" but I can't seem to link to it directly - I can only link to the primary output. The config file is created properly when I install, so it is definitely present, but I can't shortcut to it in the installer options

Comment: Ah, thank you - I was afraid it wouldn't be possible. Glad to hear it from someone with more experience than myself though! Many thanks again

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution and it's pretty easy:

1. Add Project Output for your project in the setup project
2. Select Project Output from File System in left pane and go to the properties of the project output. Then add a filter *.config to remove the .config file from your project output.
3. Rename the app.config from your actual project to the output name that your App exe ([ProductName]) will have along with the config extension ofcourse.
4. Add the [ProductName].config to your setup project as a File.
5. Create a Shortcut to that file and add it in any setup folder desktop or program folder.

Voila.
You're all set.

Answer (score 1):

I remember doing it in Vs2005 using as below:
File System Editor > Users Programs Menu 
Add> Folder
Add file (Say Config file) point it to the its location

Comment: Tried that but I get an error saying that two or more objects have the same target location - "[targetdir]\myapp.exe.config"

Comment: I should add to that comment that it flags up the exe.config and the primary output of the project as the two objects with the same target location